# Delete data onERROR (or find all which causes violates unique constraint) during UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

Is there any possibility to remove duplicated data based on data removal?

Use case:

I have a table with: PRIMARY_KEY which is composed by 3 columns: id, key, key2
Example data:

```
id   key   key2
---------------
 1     1      1
 1    ''      1
 1     3      1
```

While I try to update `key` with value `''`, I am getting `duplicate key value violates unique constraint PK_...` (which is fine), but instead I would like to remove all of those duplicates during UPDATE (in given example all the data).

I was thinking to set NULL for example and ON NULL delete, but I hope there is some other/nicer option like in insert ON CONFLICT.

Please let me know if you have sample (to avoid memory usage on app side, I would prefer to do it on db level w/o returning and selecting values).

Comment: can you please explain '...  instead I would like to remove all of those duplicates ...' ? what are the duplicates?

Comment: So, during UPDATE query I am getting violates, since DB is trying to update rows but due to the PRIMARY KEY on few columns it returns error obviously (to avoid having duplicates by design of PK), instead of returning such a violates error I would like to remove duplicated data automatically instead. And I am thinking if there is any quick approach.

Comment: It is not clear to me how a duplicate is defined.

Comment: Okay, so primary key is composed using (id, key, key2) if I update key with the same value (which is different in each of the row now) to expected EMTPY '' value will try to be exactly the same so then due to avoid duplication in DB, DB is returning duplicate key value violates unique constraint PK.